# Security warning for JavaScript and CSS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, internet-explorer

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. And I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net + JavaScript (jQuery).

I met with the following security warning in browser (at the top of the page in IE) when browse a page -- "An add-on for this web site failed to run. Check the security settings in Internet Options for potential conflicts." The function I developed works fine besides the security warnings. I am using IE 8. Any ideas why there is security warnings and how to resolve?

Here is the code I added to BlueBand.master to refer the js/css files in head section. I am developing a webpart which such script files will impact (i.e. my webpart will generate a div called "tabs" which such below scripts will impact). Any security issues?

```
 <link type="text/css" href="_layouts/test/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/test/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/test/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/test/ui/ui.tabs.js"></script>
 <link type="text/css" href="_layouts/test/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
         $("#tabs").tabs();
     });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably related to ActiveX control or scripts that is not allowed to run doe to your security settings.

You can add your website to the trusted sites list to mitigate this problem.

More info: [Internet Explorer 8 Information bar: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Internet-Explorer-8-Information-bar-frequently-asked-questions)

Comment: 1. Why do you think it is client side issue and not server side issue? 2. For javascript/css deployment in SharePoint, no need special settings for security -- just copy to layout folder and reference in master page?

Comment: well the error is on the client, so thats a good indicator :-) I am not convinced that the error is caused by the javascript you show. It could be caused by other things that goes on in the code on the page (like an activex control). Did you try and add your site to trusted sites?

Answer (score 0):

Use the MARK OF THE WEB (MOTW) workaround. It works greatly on 99% of my own projects. Thanx to the virii fload experienced in M$ enviroments since... ever, the IE team tried everything to avoid (and hopefully close) some dangerous security holes they found. Weird and poorly undocumented solutions sometimes, like this one:

- [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(VS.85).aspx)

**To sum up:**

Copy and paste this HTML comment RIGHT AFTER the !DOCTYPE line(s) into your HTML markup and your are in the game...

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

Hope it was helpful somehow... Emerson